# Name for prosodic pattern in which the last line in a verse is much shorter than all the rest

Tags: poetry, terminology

I noticed this pattern in Auden's poetry where the last line in a verse will be *much* shorter than preceding lines. Here is one of the earliest examples, taken from *Paid on Both Sides*:

> Here a scrum breaks up like a bomb, there troops
> Deploy like birds. But proudest into traps
> Have fallen. These gears which ran in oil for a week
> By week, needing no look, now will not work;
> These manors mortgaged twice to pay for love
> Go to another. <<<

This is definitely not enjambment. The closest thing that I could find is [catalexis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalectic), which describes a line of verse lacking one syllable, but this is not quite right since the last line is often shorter by much more than just one syllable.

Comment: Catalectic = lacking one syllable, [brachycatalectic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brachycatalectic) = lacking two syllables. [Some](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PEUFDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT190&lpg=PT190&dq=verse+last+line+shorter+catalexis) sources [say](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uKiC6IeFR2UC&pg=PA649&lpg=PA649&dq=verse+last+line+shorter+catalexis#v=onepage&q=catalexis&f=false) that catalexis can refer to any number of syllables lacking.

Comment: It appears to present a variant of a Sapphic stanza with an "adonic" final line.

Comment: This isn't really an example of "the last line in a verse will be much shorter than the previous lines". This is blank verse, where the break between stanzas happens in the middle of a line. Here is a longer section of this poem: *"These manors mortgaged twice to pay for love //
Go to another. //
..................O how shall man live //
Whose thought is born, child of one farcical night, //
To find him old?"* See how the five syllables of "*Go to another"* combine with those of *"O how shall man live"* to form a line of iambic pentameter. This isn't new; Shakespeare did this in his plays.

Comment: For a better example of short last lines, consider Poe's poem [*To Helen*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44888/to-helen). *"Lo! in yon brilliant window-niche //
   How statue-like I see thee stand, //
The agate lamp within thy hand! //
   Ah, Psyche, from the regions which //
   Are Holy-Land!"*